# average aggregate on nested data

Tags: graphql, hasura

What I would like to get is the average `ScoreOverall` of all the products within the List. I've tried adding some relationships but I can't get an `aggregate` "endpoint" on a nested level.

The data model:

```
List
|--ListProducts (linking table, one list to many products)
   |--ProductScore (joined view)
      |--ScoreWeighted (value I want the average across all products in this List)
```

Any clues on what the best approach for this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the built in GQL operations exposed by Hasura don't allow you to get everything you need your best bet is extending the schema with a custom SQL [function](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/schema/custom-functions.html) or [view](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/schema/views.html)